# I can't install carrot2 on win 8

Tags: java, carrot2

I want to install Carrot2 workbench in file "carrot2-workbench-win32.win32.x86_64-3.10.1" but it always displays "This app can't run on this pc". I've searched for the new workbench by downloading "carrot2-release-3.13.0" but the new workbench doesn't exist.

I use windows 8, 32 bit OS. I don't know if my Java bit is same with my bit OS, so how to check JRE bit (java runtime environment)?

And how to solve this installation problem?

Answer (score 0):

type 
`java -version`
in command to check your java version